# Outlook 2010 should restore its window position

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm running Outlook 2010 and it almost never remembers the previous window position. I would like to have it maximized on my second monitor, but it either snaps maximized to my first monitor or, far more often, restores to a smaller (not-maximized) window position.

This happens both after restarting the program and after restoring the window by starting it again (from the pinned program list) when it is minimized to the notification area.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of utilities that can maximize Outlook on your second monitor automatically. The one I use is [PTFB](http://www.ptfbpro.com/) - it's mainly for automatically handling annoying Windows prompts but it does window restores on multimonitor systems as well. It's shareware, but there are probably some freeware apps that do the same kind of thing if you Google for 'em.